# Combine 2 Arrays of Different Lengths

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, each of different counts, the example I'm working with is there's 132 in one and 136 in the other,

I need to `array_combine()` them (make the first one the key, and the second one the value). In my example I would like to keep 132 key/value pairs and drop of the extra 4 that have no corresponding match.

I have currently got this function (which I found on php.net's docs of `array_combine()`), but it isn't working:

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
            $count1 = count($arr1);
            $count2 = count($arr2);
            $numofloops = $count2/$count1;

            $i = 0;
            while($i < $numofloops){
                $arr3 = array_slice($arr2, $count1*$i, $count1);
                $arr4[] = array_combine($arr1,$arr3);
                $i++;
            }

            return $arr4;
     }
```

I keep getting back

> Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters
>   should have an equal number of elements on the line that starts with
>   $arr4[] = ...

Any advice would help,

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
    $count = min(count($arr1), count($arr2));
    return array_combine(array_slice($arr1, 0, $count), array_slice($arr2, 0, $count));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a one-liner:

```
$res = array_combine(array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2), array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1));
```

Answer (score -3):

here is perfect function in PHP itself called "array_combine()"

```
  /*-----------------------------------------------------------
  | Parameter            | Description                        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | array1  Required.   | An array, specifying the keys       |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | array2  Required.   | An array, specifying the values     |
  -----------------------------------------------------------*/

$array1 = ('John','Mark','Ester');
$array2 = (1111,2222);

// if some elements dont exists, "add" them...
if(count($array1) != count($array2))
{
  foreach($array as $key => $value):
      if(!isset($array2[$key]) $array2[$key] = NULL;
  endforeach;
}

// now, combine them in classic way...
$combined = array_combine($array1,$array2);
```