# i want to apply array_combine to unequal arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i want a key value pair from two different arrays
there are two cases. 1) both are equal 2) second array is big than first array

my code is

```
$array1=array("anu","jinu");
$array2=array("1","2","0");
```

i want to make a pair like

```
  anu-1

  jinu-2
```

if `$array1` elements are finished then do not have to pair with `$array2`
from the example we can ignore the third element in $array2
i tried to apply array_combine,but its not practical with two unequal arrays
if anybody knows solution please help me

Comment: @mickmackusa i also saw that,but didnt understood well,thats why asked . :(

Comment: That's okay.  In the future, if you find a duplicate or near duplicate that **didn't** help you, you should list it in your question.  This proves to volunteers that you put effort into researching the question.  The good news is this newer page provides a wider range of correct answers than that one.  Please update your question to state that `$array2` will never be shorter than `$array1`.

Comment: @mickmackusa  updated

Comment: After re-reading my duplicate link very carefully, I will admit that that page was a RUBBISH dupe link.  These are much better suited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769213/combine-2-arrays-of-different-lengths & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394980/warning-array-combine-both-parameters-should-have-an-equal-number-of-element/19396994#19396994  If anyone has the superpowers to update my closure with these new links, please do me the favor because I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any loop and simply you have to use `array_combine`. Try following solution with `array_slice`

```
$array1=array("anu","jinu");
$array2=array("1","2","0");
$cnt1 = count($array1);
$cnt2 = count($array2);
if($cnt1>$cnt2)
    $array1=array_slice($array1, 0, $cnt2);
elseif($cnt2>$cnt1)
    $array2=array_slice($array2, 0, $cnt1);

$arr = array_combine($array1,$array2);
print_r($arr);
```

Note : It will check for both array. and take length of shorter array from both

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/OJlTV)

**EDIT**

If its fix that always **array2** length is equal or more  than  **array1** then you can ignore if -elseif statement. For that try following code

```
$array1=array("anu","jinu");
$array2=array("1","2","0");

$cnt1 = count($array1);
$array2=array_slice($array2, 0, $cnt1);   

$arr = array_combine($array1,$array2);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: could you please tell whats the else if statement do with array_slice?

Comment: Its for check length of array if array 1 is bigger then it will take only 2nd array's equivalent length array and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $array1=array("anu","jinu");
    $array2=array("1","2","0");

    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){

     $newarray[$array2[$key]] = $value;

    }

    print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: How do you know which array is longer?  Just guess and hope?  Pick the wrong one and you will be trying to access a non-existent element. :(

Comment: @user7441072 This answer will cause Notices when the sizes are unbalanced the other way.

Comment: @mickmackusa  yes,you are right.but in my issue,always second array will be large or both are equal.

Comment: @user7441072 that vital information should be in your question.  AND if that is true, then you should be awarding the green tick to Sachin, Arun or Erwin

Comment: @mickmackusa  B Desai solved the issue in every cases and also he gave explanation with demo. thats why i  gave green tick to him

Comment: @user7441072 Well that's actually a good reason.  I do support quality over speed.

Comment: @mickmackusa thats right,Thank You again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code which output like you want

```
$arr1=array("anu","jinu");
$arr2=array("1","2","0");
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
   $newArr[$value] = $arr2[$key];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: How do you know which array is longer?  Just guess and hope?  Pick the wrong one and you will be trying to access a non-existent element. :(

Comment: @user7441072 This answer will cause Notices when the sizes are unbalanced the other way.

Comment: Here I assume that you always prefer to work with $array1. If this is not the case then you can use count() function of php and according to that use array_slice() function

Answer (score 1):

Using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
// Slice array2 to match count with array1
$slice = array_slice($array2, 0, count($array1)); 
// Combine using array1 as key, sliced array as value
$combine = array_combine($array1, $slice);        

print_r($combine); // Print result
```

Comment: How do you know which array is longer?  Just guess and hope?  Pick the wrong one and `array_combine()` will barf at you. :(

Answer (score 1):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ff4d858be057c5e42313e70e582a329d6062b02))

```
$array1=array("anu","jinu");
$array2=array("1","2","0");

foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($array2[$k])) break;  // avoid "Notice: Undefined offset" and write early exit from loop
    $result[$v]=$array2[$k];
}

var_export($result);
```

Or

```
var_export(array_combine(array_intersect_key($array1,$array2),array_intersect_key($array2,$array1)));
```

Either Output:

```
array (
  'anu' => '1',
  'jinu' => '2',
)
```

Edit:

The OP says the second array will always be larger so, these are leaner methods:

```
foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
    $result[$v]=$array2[$k];
}    
var_export($result);
```

and

```
var_export(array_combine($array1,array_slice($array2,0,sizeof($array1))));
```

and

```
var_export(array_combine($array1,array_intersect_key($array2,$array1)));
```